# How to see the local variable in DDC-I debugger?

Tags: debugging, embedded, powerpc, rtos

I am trying to see the index value of for loop in DDC-I debugger and it always shows me ERROR.

With the assembly of the same, it shows the following instruction:

```
cmp cr7,0,r20,r23
```

so it's comparing `r20` and `r23` but both of these registers don't hold the index value. I am not sure what is `cr7` ?

Comment: What CPU are you using ? PowerPC ?

Comment: its DEOS RTOS based small embedded system..

Comment: Sure, but what CPU ? It looks like a PowerPC instruction to me ?

Comment: yeah it is PowerPC CPU

Comment: OK - cleaned up question and fixed tags for you.

Comment: thanks a lot for the edit

Answer (score 1):

In short, most embedded tool chains (including the ones you pay for) are horrible about reconstructing local/automatic variables in even lightly optimized code.  A lot of them simply can't reconstruct variables that never have storage because they live in registers the whole time (loop index variables like the one you can't see are typical cases).  Some even have issues with interim computation holders, and arguments (since they're almost always passed as registers).

Typical strategies might be:

1. Temporarily turning off optimizations around the code in question
2. Temporarily moving the variable in question to the global scope
3. Becoming proficient at reading disassembly.

This isn't a terribly practical answer, but it is surprising for a lot of people that are new to the embedded world or never had the luxury of a source level debugger on their embedded platform.

Comment: Rather than moving the variable to global scope, temporarily declare it as volatile in place.

Comment: Yeah, seems reading dissembley is the only way to get or to play with volatile.

Answer (score 0):

On PowerPC there are eight CR fields, `cr0` to `cr7`. If you don't specify a CR field for a compare result the default is `cr0`, but in this case `cr7` is specified and so the flags in field `cr7` will indicate the result of the compare operation. There are 4 condition code bits in each CR field: `lt`, `gt`, `eq` and `so`. Typically the compare will be followed by a conditional branch, `bc`.

There is some useful info in this IBM developerWorks article: [Assembly language for Power Architecture, Part 3: Programming with the PowerPC branch processor](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-powasm3/index.html).